# Google chrome css issues

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have just updated my google chrome to latest version that is 17....I was working on the following website http://www.melbourneheartcare.com.au/ and on the left side, the three items do not align properly. Everything looks fine in firefox. The website was showing fine in previous version of google chrome too. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: I keep getting JS errors, everytime the script runs, I'm over 22 erors at the moment...Check in devtools

Answer (score 0):

In your `<li>` tags replace `<h2>` tag with `<span><font size=xx>  your text </font></span>`